# Controlling CCS Animations

Tags: css, css-animations

I am using purely CSS to create a dynamically opening and closing sidebar based on the view-port with of the page. I have a couple issues with my code however:

1. How can I prevent an animation when the screen first loads? That is, I simply want the sidebar to be opened or closed on first loading, and then animated when the view-port is adjusted.
2. Why do I have to have two separate animations? Notice I have two identical keyframes `toggle` and `toggle1`, which are used for closing and opening respectively. If I try to use just `toggle` for both animations, the animation occurs instantly. Any workaround without duplicated code?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #123456;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #sidebar {
    animation: toggle 200ms ease-in 1 reverse forwards;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #sidebar {
    animation: toggle1 200ms ease-out 1 normal forwards;
  }
}

@keyframes toggle {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}

@keyframes toggle1 {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: -200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple transition instead of animation, and 1 media query

```
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #123456;
  height: 100vh;
  transition:left 500ms ease;
  left:0;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #sidebar {
    left: -200px;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufoste1y/3/

You can also use transform:translateX, which should provide [better performance](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/).

```
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #123456;
  height: 100vh;
  transition:transform 500ms ease;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #sidebar {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufoste1y/8/

Comment: Thanks! Would you actually recommend this in a website? Is it unnatural, too busy, or necessary?

Comment: @BenjaminBrownlee I don't think people actually resizes their viewports at all (except when switching the mobile orientation, but the browser will deal with that in a different way) So it's mostly a not really needed eye candy that probably almost no one will ever see. But also, it won't hurt to have it there either, since it's just a single line of CSS with virtually zero  impact on performance, specially if you go with the translateX approach, which gets accelerated via GPU.

Answer (score 0):

In order to force the sidebar to be opened or closed by default, that **cannot** be done with raw CSS. You'd need JavaScript to wait until the page has finished loading, and then dynamically update the element to have a class or similar that the CSS animation applies to.

As for the duplicate code, you can certainly just use `toggle`. It not working for you was probably a result of you forgetting to also change the `@media` `animation` reference from `toggle1` to `toggle`.

Here's an example showing the sidebar staying open by default with the aid of JavaScript. The animation is now triggering only on the `.loaded` class, and the JavaScript applies the `loaded` class to the element 1000 milliseconds after the page has loaded, meaning that it won't trigger the animation initially.

Having said that, you'll probably only want to trigger the slide on some sort of condition anyway, and JavaScript would be much better suited to that :)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
    sidebar.classList.add("loaded");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #123456;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #sidebar.loaded {
    animation: toggle 200ms ease-in 1 reverse forwards;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #sidebar.loaded {
    animation: toggle 200ms ease-out 1 normal forwards;
  }
}

@keyframes toggle {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: The sidebar is still sliding onload and now doesn't slide when view-port is adjusted.